# admin django. Add the total price in admin

Tags: python, django, admin

hello I have to add a line or for example total_price = 123312 in admin

models.py

```
class Exit(models.Model):
  description= models.CharField(max_length=50)
  data_uscita = models.DateField('data uscita')
  price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, null=True,blank=True)
```

admin.py

```
  class ExitAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     list_display =['description','price','total_exit']

def total_exit(self, request): 
    total = Exit.objects.all().aggregate(tot=Sum('price'))['tot']
    return total
```

but is not ok because j have a columns with the total_exit that are repeated. I want total write only just once

I'm using Python 2.7.11

Answer (score 1):

If what you need it's a function that returns the total of all outcomes (exits in your case), this is how the function goes:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

#other code you may need

def get_total(self, request): 
    return Exit.objects.aggregate(total=Sum('price'))
```

But, as you only got one price by outcome it doesn't make any sense to make a aggregate function because you should need multiple prices by outcome and a cost model perse.